# How to determine the cipher used from a binary blob

Tags: openssl, openssh

A client of mine uses a ReSI to manage remote control. I have never heard of
ReSI and apperently it runs only with a windows client.

The configuration file (that we've got form the client) has an entry `sshkey` and I would like to extract
that and convert it to OpenSSH format so that I can use the openSSH client.

I can see that the key is encoded in base64 and I extracted it into a file. `file`
tells me this:

```
$ file enc_key
enc_key: openssl enc'd data with salted password, base64 encoded
```

I decoded the base64 file and got a binary blob that starts with `Salted__`. I
also used `openssl enc` with

```
$ openssl enc -in enc_key -d  -a -out enc_key.bin
Salted__....
```

and I got the same binary blob and when I run `file` on it I get:

```
$ file enc_key.bin
enc_key.bin: openssl enc'd data with salted password
```

I have the passphrase (our client sent me the passphrase in a separate email) but
I'm still unable to decrypt the file even with the passphrase. I tried all
supported ciphers:

```
for cipher in $(openssl enc -list | tail -n +2) ; do openssl enc ${cipher} -d -in enc_key.bin -pass "pass:<THE PASSPHASE>" ; done
```

yields either an error messages or a binary blobs.

Is it possible to determine how this the data was encrypted in the first place,
which cipher was used?

Comment: I am not sure retro engenering is a solution, can't customer provide you at least editor's web or help page ?

Comment: @Archemar: I don't like this kind of solution either, I'll have to ask the customer, but I'm not sure if If the customer can provide such information.

Comment: I would suggest that a cipher, which has some form of fingerprint, is a poor cipher?

Comment: @garethTheRed No. The “raw” ciphertext should be impossible to identify (a good encryption method produces output that is indistinguishable from random), but there's nothing wrong with having metadata next to the ciphertext that says which algorithm was used.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - fair point, but that metadata would be in the container, such as CMS/PKCS#7 rather than the cipher itself?  I suppose that does suggest that it may be possible to determine the cipher, depending on the format of the file.